# .tailSet supposedly returns NavigableSet, but seems to return TreeSet

Tags: java, treeset

This may seem like a weird question but I'm a little confused: In Java, the method NavigableSet.tailSet(Object) supposedly returns a SortedSet, and tailSet(Object, boolean) returns a NavigableSet. But it seems to me like they actually both return a TreeSet.

```
TreeSet<String> mts= new TreeSet<String>();
Object whatTypeAmI = mts.tailSet("bla");
```

I mean...

- The oracle pages say tailSet(Object) returns a SortedSet and tailSet(Object, boolean) a NavigableSet
- When I hover my mouse over the methods in Eclipse it says so too
- The fact that you can't directly assign the result of tailSet(String) to a NavigableSet without casting it supports this as well

BUT:

- When I run a code in debug mode and examine mts.tailSet("bla"), it tells me it's a variable of type TreeSet
- mts.tailSet("bla").getClass() returns TreeSet
- mts.tailSet("bla") instanceof TreeSet returns true.

Why is that?

EDIT:

I know that TreeSet implements NavigableSet which extends SortedSet which extends Set. I know it makes sense for a TreeSet to be recognized as a NavigableSet. But a NavigableSet shouldn't be recognized as a TreeSet.

The point of this question isn't so much practical use as it is theoretical. (I'm studying for a test. I need to be able to tell if code will compile or not). If tailSet returns a TreeSet, then how come this doesn't compile?

```
TreeSet<String> tree = mytreeset.tailSet("xx");
```

Why do I need to add a cast to TreeSet?

Comment: I went down to the pet store to buy a dog, but when I examined it later at home, I saw they'd sold me a Doberman! They lied to me! Well, no, they didn't. A Doberman is a kind of dog, and a TreeSet is a kind of SortedSet. We both got what was promised.

Comment: I know that. But Set <= SortedSet <= NavigableSet <= TreeSet
If what the API says is correct and it returns a SortedSet, then it should NOT be a TreeSet.

Comment: "Dog <= Doberman. If what the API says is correct and it returns a Dog, then it should NOT be a Doberman." Does that sound like it makes sense? It sounds kind of fishy, right?

Comment: Your edit suggests you might need to brush up on the difference between compile-time and run-time types, a.k.a. static vs dynamic types. tailSet only promises to return a SortedSet, so you can't directly assign the return value to a variable of type TreeSet because you don't know until run-time what kind of SortedSet you'll get.

Comment: As for your first post: well in real life it's not possible for something to be only a Dog without it also being a subtype like a poodle or whatever, in Java it is. If the API says it returns a Dog, then it might return a Poodle, which is indeed not a Doberman.
But your second post makes sense. It seems to return the same type as the source collection it was used on. So it doesn't promise a TreeSet just incase it was used on a SortedSet, in which case it could only return a SortedSet.

Comment: It's not possible for something to be only a SortedSet without it also being a subtype like a TreeSet or whatever either! SortedSet is an interface. (That's less important than it might sound, since methods that declare a concrete class as their return type can also return subclass instances, but it might help break some mental blocks.)

Comment: Hm ok, that's true. Forgot about that. (But it could theoretically be something that implements SortedSet that's not a TreeSet. But obviously that's not relevant.)

Answer (score 1):

`NavigableSet` and `SortedSet` are both interfaces that are implemented by `TreeSet`.  Both methods could also return a `ConcurrentSkipListSet` if they wanted to since it also implements both interfaces.

Comment: (myTreeSet instanceof NavigableSet) returns true, that makes sense, and (myNavigableSet instanceof TreeSet) should return false. So how come (whatWasReturnedByTailSet instanceof TreeSet) returns true too, if it supposedly returns a NavigableSet?